# TCL CSV quoting character

Tags: tcl

how I add quoting character using csv:

```
% package require csv
0.7.3

% set l [list "21" "Some test" "Some test"]
% ::csv::join $l {,} {"}
21,Some test,Some test
```

I want output like
"21","Some test","Some test"

Answer (score 2):

The `csv` package does not provide such quoting, unless you trick it into doing it.

One can surely argue that it should simply provide an option to do it, but try this instead:

```
package require struct::list

set l {1 "Some Text" "Some Test"}
set r [join [struct::list map $l {format {"%s"}}] ","]
puts $r
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to:

- Make Tcl not strip your double quotes;
- Disable `csv`'s escaping (which defaults to `"`)

```
% set L [list {"21"} {"Some test"} {"Some test"}]
{"21"} {"Some test"} {"Some test"}
% csv::join $L , {}
"21","Some test","Some test"
```

Note that this does not solve the issue of one of your values having a `"` character somewhere in the middle — if this can happen, you should somehow escape such characters in a way your target CSV processor understands.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not the best, but works. There might be corner cases that you need to watch for. It does not require altering the items in the list, nor does it needs the CSV package.

```
set theList [list "21" "Some test" "Some test"]
set quotedCSV "\"[join $theList {","}]\""
puts $quotedCSV
```

Basically, `quotedCSV = quote + ( theList, separated by quote+comma+quote ) + quote`. My suggestion is to go with the CSV, unless you really need the quotes.